# Google Cloud SQL 5.7 - Database disappearing

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

We have a  Cloud SQL instance using MySQL 5.7 which has about 30 DB in it. Recently we are finding a rare issue that clears all the tables in our DB and makes it appear as an empty DB. Every week a different DB gets empty.

We previously used MySQL 5.6 in our Cloud SQL instance and we didn't face this problem in the last two years. However, we have face this problem 3 times in the last month :(.

The following error is thrown:

```
14:57:53    Error loading schema content    Error Code: 1049 Unknown database 'wp-map'
```

Even though the DB name is visible we are not allowed to use it.

> Is there any problem due to using upper case in the database name, as the DB name is shown in upper case in the Cloud Console?

Comment: To address the matter of using upper case letters, I would suggest for you to check your [database flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) and set the lower_case_table_names flag to 1. That way all your tables and databases will be case insensitive and the use of upper case letters will not be taken into account (wp-map and Wp-map would be treated as the same name). In the link I provided you can find out how to check and set database flags.

Comment: Can you confirm whether or not Rodrigo's comment was helpful for solving your issue and if not could you provide us with full error trace?

Comment: have you found a solution ? I got same issue today for no reason why it refresh from zero .